# Access JSON values in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{"coord":{"lon":73.69,"lat":17.8},"sys":{"message":0.109,"country":"IN","sunrise":1393032482,"sunset":1393074559},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":293.999,"temp_min":293.999,"temp_max":293.999,"pressure":962.38,"sea_level":1025.86,"grnd_level":962.38,"humidity":78},"wind":{"speed":1.15,"deg":275.503},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1393077388,"id":1264491,"name":"Mahabaleshwar","cod":200}
```

I am trying to fetch description from the weather from the json above but getting errors in php. I have tried the below php code:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($contents, true);
$result=array();

foreach($jsonDecode as $data)
{

  foreach($data{'weather'} as $data2)
  {

     echo $data2{'description'};
  }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am new in using json.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error? If so, which one? If you're just trying to get the weather description, you can simply do: `$result = $jsonDecode['weather'][0]['description'];`. [**See demo**](https://eval.in/104555)

Comment: You only need to call json_deconde once.

Comment: I am calling json_decode only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use square brackets (`[]`) for accessing array elements, not curly ones (`{}`).

Thus, your code should be changed to reflect these changes:

```
foreach($data['weather'] as $data2)
{
    echo $data2['description'];
}
```

Also, your outer `foreach` loop will cause your code to do something completely different than you intend, you should just do this:

```
foreach($jsonDecode['weather'] as $data2)
{
    echo $data2['description'];
}
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting for one. Two, show what `var_dump($jsonDecode)` returns.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven: Arrays can be accessed using `{}` syntax just fine. That's not the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your $jsonDecode seems to be an array, so this should work-

```
foreach($jsonDecode['weather'] as $data)
{
    echo $data['description'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access data directly with scopes

```
$json = '{"coord":{"lon":73.69,"lat":17.8},"sys":{"message":0.109,"country":"IN","sunrise":1393032482,"sunset":1393074559},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":293.999,"temp_min":293.999,"temp_max":293.999,"pressure":962.38,"sea_level":1025.86,"grnd_level":962.38,"humidity":78},"wind":{"speed":1.15,"deg":275.503},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1393077388,"id":1264491,"name":"Mahabaleshwar","cod":200}';
$jsonDecode = json_decode($json, true);

echo $jsonDecode['weather'][0]['description'];
//output Sky is Clear
```

As you can see wheater` is surrounded with scopes so that means it is another array. You can loop throw that array if you have more than one result

```
foreach($jsonDecode['weather'] as $weather)
{
     echo $weather['description'];
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://codepad.org/c4cLmsOt)

Comment: Weather is an array of its own, which would imply that there will be more items than just one :)

Comment: @RainFromHeaven that's why i placed both way as well as a sample which you didn't ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, I must have had a moment of brief insanity ;)

Comment: @Rain hehe not a prob

Answer (score 0):

you have to access "weather" with "[]" operator

like this,

```
$data["weather"]
```

Comment: One small note: his code is explicitly passing `true` as the second value to `json_decode` which means the content of `$jsonDecode` is an associative array, not an object. http://ie1.php.net/json_decode

Comment: did not help. I get this: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @sonu703 remove the outer foreach and instead of $data in inner foreach use $jsonDecode

Answer (score 0):

If the result of decode is an array, use:

```
$data['weather']
```

If the result is an object, use:

```
$data->weather
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several things worth answering in your question:

Q: What's the difference between `json_decode($data)` and `json_decode($data, true)`?
A: The former converts JSON object to a PHP object, the latter creates an associative array: https://www.php.net/json_decode

In either case, there is no point on iterating over the result. You probably want to access just the 'weather' field:

`$o = json_decode($data)` => use `$weather = $o->weather`
`$a = json_decode($data, true)` => use `$weather = $a['weather']`

Once you have the 'weather' field, look carefully what it is:
`"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}]`

It's an array, containing a single object. That means you will either need to iterate over it, or use `$clearSky = $weather[0]`. In this case, it does not matter which approach of json_decode did you choose => JSON array is always decoded to a PHP (numeric indexed) array.

But, once you get `$clearSky`, you are accessing the object and it again matters, which approach you chose - use arrow or brackets, similarly to the first step.

So, the correct way to get for exaple the weather description would be either of these:

`json_decode($data)->weather[0]->description`
`json_decode($data, true)['weather'][0]['description']`

Note: In the latter case, dereferencing result of the function call is supported only in PHP 5.4 or newer. In PHP 5.3 or older, you have to create a variable.

Note: I also encourage you to always check if the expected fields are actually set in the result, using `isset`. Otherwise you will try to access undefined field, which raises an error.