# How to get the values from JSON Array Stored as Value in JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, nested

```
`{
    "student": [{
        "name": "Alice",
        "rno": "187654"
    }]
}`
```

I am trying to get the value of rno using PHP code

```
`$data = json_decode($json, true);
 foreach ($data as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'] ;
    $number= $item['rno'] ;
}`
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access JSON values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956249/access-json-values-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sahil Gulati's code is more prefect and right way to parse the json in php

here is an other way to parse the json data in php

```
<?php

$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $val) {
        echo $name = $val['name'];
        echo $number = $val['rno'];
    }
}

 ?>
```

the above code that i have shared you can understand easily. but after learning that how to parse json data in php you should use @Sahil Gulati's mathod.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this to:**

```
foreach ($data as $item)
```

**This:**

```
foreach ($data["student"] as $item)
```

[**Try code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779492)

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data["student"] as $item)
{
    $name = $item['name'];
    $number = $item['rno'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a closer look at the structure of the json encoded data. That helps to implement a clean iteration:

```
<?php
$input = <<<JSON
{
    "student": [{
        "name": "Alice",
        "rno": "187654"
    }]
}
JSON;
$data = json_decode($input);
$output = [];
array_walk($data->student, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = $entry->rno;
});
print_r($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 187654
)
```

The output format has been chosen as an array, since the json structure suggests that *multiple* students can be contained.

---

If you are only directly interested in the `rno` property of the first entry in the `student` array, then you can access it directly:

```
<?php
$input = <<<JSON
{
    "student": [{
        "name": "Alice",
        "rno": "187654"
    }]
}
JSON;
$data = json_decode($input);
var_dump($data->student[0]->rno);
```

The output of that variant obviously is:

```
string(6) "187654"
```